# Labelling x- and y-axis by the corresponding variable's name in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, label

this sounds like a very trivial question at first, but no one managed to help me thus far, hence I'm reaching out to you all.

I'd like to do the following:

I'm writing a simple function that allows me to plot two variables against each other, with a third variable coloring the observation points (depending on the corresponding value of the color variable). The code looks like that:

```
scatterplot <- function(data_used, x.variable, y.variable, color.variable) {
  
  ggplot(data_used, aes(x=x.variable, y = y.variable)) +
    geom_point(aes_string(color = color.variable)) 
  
}

scatterplot(data_used = example_data, x.variable = example_data$education, 
            y.variable = example_data$wages, 
            color.variable = example_data$sex)
```

What I would like R to do now is to label the x- and y-axis (respectively) by the corresponding variable's name that I decide to be plotted. In this example here, x-axis would be 'education', y-axis would be 'wages'.

I tried to simply put `+ labs (x = x.variable, y = y.variable)` and it doesn't work (when doing that, R labels the axes by the variable values!). By default, R just names the axes "x.variable" and "y.variable".

Can someone help me achieve what I'm trying to do?

Best regards,

xifrix

Comment: Can you share your data with us using `dput(example_data)` so we can try and reproduce your plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jpenzer's answer is a good one.  Here it is without the quasi-quotation stuff.

```
scatterplot <- function(data_used, x.variable, y.variable, color.variable) {
  
  ggplot(data_used, aes_string(x=x.variable, y = y.variable)) +
    geom_point(aes_string(color = color.variable)) +
    labs(x=x.variable, y=y.variable, colour=color.variable)
  
}
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(am = as.factor(am)) %>% 
scatterplot(., x.variable = "hp", 
            y.variable = "mpg", 
            color.variable = "am")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you very much for your help, the code worked. I really appreciate you helping me on this.
Am I correct that the main difference to my code was the re-coding of my color-variable to a factor object (differently put, is the 'mutate' part the crucial one?
If you could provide short verbal intuition for your code, that'd be amazing.

Comment: If the `color.variable` is not a factor, then you will get a color ramp instead of two different labelled points.  It is not crucial to get the output, but it does make the output look better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the quasi-quotation stuff is 100% necessary in hindsight, but this is the pattern I use for similar needs:

```r
my_scatterplot <- function(data, x, y){
  .x = rlang::enquo(x)
  .y = rlang::enquo(y)
  data %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+
    geom_point()+
    labs(x = .x, 
         y = .y)
}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you, it should though. edit: Should add after DaveArmstrong's answer, the function would be called without quotes for the x / y variable e.g.

```r
diamonds %>% my_scatterplot(price, table)
```

Comment: Hi, a big thanks to you as well, although I perceive your code to be (at least for me!) the least intuitive one. Still, it worked and so I appreciate you taking your time to provide me with some insights.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a column name in the function you could use double curly braces  `{{...}}` around the desired column name in the function body:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

scatterplot <- function(data_used, x.variable, y.variable, color.variable) {
  
  ggplot(data_used, aes_string({{x.variable}}, {{y.variable}})) +
    geom_point(aes_string(color = {{color.variable}})) +
    labs(x=x.variable, y=y.variable, colour=color.variable)
  
}


scatterplot(mtcars %>% mutate(am = as.factor(am)), x.variable = "mpg", 
            y.variable = "hp", 
            color.variable = "am")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi TarJae, your answer is pretty similar to Dave's. This also worked and seems even more straightforward, as you implemented the mutate-operator into the line of code that tells the function what to plot (Is there a certain term for this line of code, namely where I determine the inputs for a function?).
Thank you very much for your help as well, this is very nice of you.